# Watching for when any element changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a rather unique issue in jquery to solve. I have a div wrapper:

`<div class="formWrapper"></div>`

This contains a set of elements that should, when they change (doesn't matter which element changes) - should (for example) be stored in a data object, and that object logged to the console - *for now*.

So:

```
        <div class="formWrapper">
            <div class="floatRight">
                <div>
                    <label>Select a Project Manager</label>
                    <select class="projectManager">
                         <?php foreach($projectManagers as $name){ ?>
                         <option><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Select a Division</label>
                    <select class="division">
                         <?php foreach($divisions as $division){ ?>
                         <option><?php echo $division['division_name']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="floatLeft">
                <div>
                    <label>Select a Client</label>
                    <select class="client">
                         <?php foreach($clients as $client){ ?>
                         <option><?php echo $client['client_company_name']; ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Choose a Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="date" placeholder="Click to choose a date"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Pretty simple to see whats going on. But what if `projectManager` changes or `divison` or ... both, or all the elements, a simple [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) might work for one element but I need to watch all the element and dynamically update a data object such that each time an element changes, the console spits out a different data object.

**The end goal**

Have a data object, for example `data = {pm : pm_selected_value}` for if the user JUST selects pm and then, if they change division - the data object should update to should: `data = {pm : pm_selected_value, divsion: division_selected_value}` and so on ...

I know how to get the value of each element, I don't know how to create a dynamic data object like this while watching each element.

The catch, and I think `change()` from reading the docs does this, is that even if I have a data object like this:

`data = {pm : pm_selected_value, divsion: division_selected_value}`

and I go an update the pm (so selecting a different pm), the data object should instantly update to reflect that change:

`data = {pm : pm_selected_NEW_value, divsion: division_selected_value}`

Now I can apply `.change()` to each element - but is there no way to apply it to a div to say - "excuse me mr JavaScript - please watch all form elements inside here for change, k thanks."

Comment: When you say (when any element changes), you really mean when any input's value changes, right? you literally can simply apply .change to a parent element that contains input elements.

Comment: What about `$(document).on('change','.formWrapper input', function(){});` ?

Comment: @KevinB yes that's what I mean, can you please elaborate more - with a possible example? Cristy, I don't follow, I think I get the concept - but could you provide an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do it listen for any select value to get changed within the `<div class="formWrapper"></div>` so you should target the `<div>` and attach the change event to child `<select>`s

```
var choices = new Object();

$('.formwrapper').on('change', 'select', function(){

    choices[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();

    console.log(choices);

});
```

One thing you should do is provide a unique `name=""` for each `<select>` so that you know what you are dealing with inside of the anonymous `function()`

Comment: Yours only allows one object, my console.log looks like:

`Object {undefined: "ABBBerMac-Calgary"}
Object {undefined: "Scott Diamond"} `

Which is not what I wanted

Comment: Please refer to the sentence directly after the code I posted. If `$(this).attr('name')` isn't sufficient then use `$(this).attr('class')` but I strongly advise against it since you can apply more than one class to an element and it will screw up your object